# Linux commandline find and add up numbers

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, sum, substring

In the log file which may contain information of different form, I need to grep only those lines that contain substring "ABC", then among chosen lines extract (it always exists) the number of Kb at the end (pattern is ": %n Kb", where %n is the number from 0 and above). Finally I need to add up all the values to get the amount of memory used by an app.

```
2016-01-14T16:15:01.695Z [INFO] application - ABC 5f18dda7-a30a-44f5-82dd-69d4b5469245: 118 Kb
2016-01-14T16:15:04.535Z [INFO] application - 5f18dda7-a30a-44f5-82dd-69d4b5469245
```

Comment: Did you already try something?

Answer (score 1):

`grep` isn't a verb, but `awk` is!

```
awk '/ABC/ {s+= $(NF-1)} END {print s "Kb"}'
```

should work (untested)

Comment: `awk` is the way to go here, indeed. Can you explain what the term *verb* means in this case? I failed to translate it in this contexts.

Comment: I just mean that using 'grep' as a verb in the phrase 'I need to grep only those lines...' is causing the OP to miss the obvious solution.  'grep' is often used as a verb in common usage but 'awk' rarely is, and I think that is a travesty.

Comment: Interesting explanation! :) Seconded!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following chain:

```
grep ABC logfile.txt | egrep -o "[0-9]+ Kb" | cut -f1 -d" "|  paste -s -d+ | bc
```

Comment: This works even if the the "kb field" is not at the end.

Comment: @HordonFreeman does ` ... | paste -s -d+  - | bc `  work (ie. with an additional dash for stdin?). What version of paste do you use (paste --version)? You might need for this GNU paste from coreutils, as other might not read directly from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to grep only those lines that contain substring "ABC", then among chosen lines extract (it always exists) the number of Kb at the end

This looks like a job for awk. The number is always the second last column, which awk can extract easily:

```
awk '/ABC/ { print $(NF-1) }' filename_here
```

Here `NF-1` is the index of the second-last column, and `$` gets the value in that column.

But you want to sum it up, rather than just extract. That's a simple task, and it shows off a slightly more advanced usage of `awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { sum = 0; }
    /ABC/ { sum += $(NF-1); }
    END { print sum; }
' filename_here
```

Technically speaking you can omit the entire BEGIN line, but I consider it good style to be up-front about the variables you expect to use in the program.